# how to import Materialrecent design in android app

Tags: android, github

I am trying to import Github library about Material design from  https://github.com/ZieIony/MaterialRecents but I am facing this type of error:

```
("Error:Dependency com.github.ZieIony:MaterialRecents:d2aec46f48 on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: C:\Users\Talha\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.ZieIony\MaterialRecents\d2aec46f48\494f96d345471f38b6f3f4c1c42347a2b42f8303\MaterialRecents-d2aec46f48.apk")
```

**My Gradle is**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.talha.myrecentdesign"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.github.ZieIony:MaterialRecents:d2aec46f48'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}
```

**and**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

   buildscript {
       repositories {
           jcenter()

       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'

           // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
           // in the individual module build.gradle files
       }
   }

   allprojects {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
           maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
           }

   }

   task clean(type: Delete) {
       delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
```

I have searched from many sites but not find the exact solution. Please help me.

Comment: add dependency in gradle compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

Comment: again this error #Bensal

Answer (score 0):

The library you are reffering to uses CardView which is part of the android support design library, so you have to add a dependency for that aswell.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```